# Screen -L disable logging

Tags: gnu-screen

So I actually have two important questions:

1. I know that **screen -L** enables auto-logging of screen to a file by default, **screenlog.0, screenlog.1, etc.** However, if I no longer want to log files, how do I disable logging? Running **screen -L** again won't stop the automatic logging.
2. Also, if the bottom of my screen session shows **+100 more lines**... or xx amount of additional lines, is it possible to get the entirety of these lines to output to a screen log file? Currently, screen will actually log the **+100 more lines** without displaying the additional lines in the log file.